Is there a way to annotate the count for all objects without grouping by another column?
I have code that looks like the following:
filtered_queryset = Object.objects.filter(...misc filters)

match time:
  case "year":
    qs = filtered_queryset.annotate(year=TruncYear("created_at")).values("year")
  case "month":
    qs = filtered_queryset.annotate(month=TruncMonth("created_at")).values("month")
  case "week":
    qs = filtered_queryset.annotate(week=TruncWeek("created_at")).values("week")
  case _:
    qs = filtered_queryset

final_count = qs.annotate(count=Count("id"))

In each case, I am expecting data that looks like the following
# Each case
{
  [{
    "TIME": ...
    "count": ...
   },
   ...
   ]
}
# Default
{
  [{
    "count": ...
   }]
}

I was under the impression that Count() was a terminal expression in django and that the queryset would be evaluated. However, the default case returns a queryset instead of evaluating. What am I missing here that causes it to not evaluate the queryset?
I know that I can just call filtered_queryset.count() instead of trying to do this via annotate, but it causes extra code to check for the default case and adds code smell.
